# Writing SCO Unix ISO file to USB failed

Tags: bootable, sco, openserver

I have downloaded **OpenServer** 5 from this [link](https://mega.nz/file/DNU10Lbb#UYRvDkvmJGGQGNMJu9dkj5N5eZKMMUxHA0_11uiFw8w).
I created a vm machine (Vmware workstation) and used this ISO file as CD-ROM image file(IDE). Everything works fine and the vm boots from CD-ROM normally and I can intall the OS, but when I try to write the ISO file as a bootable USB, my motherboards ( 2 different models ) don't recognized it as a bootable USB. I have used multiple programs to make the bootable USB like **rufus** and **PowerISO** with multiple different options with no success.

What is wrong here and what should I do?

Comment: "_I have downloaded OpenServer 5_" - [why?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenServer#SCO_OpenServer)

Comment: Archaeology, maybe?

Comment: @roaima Because of an old graphical software developed in SCO Unix in 1990s.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Because a giant German firm decided to develop an application in Openserver back in 1990s.

Comment: Rufus would be the way forward, or maybe syslinux

Comment: A search shown v5.0.6 had very limited USB support. And another search shows that you need a `UHCI` USBv1.x chip, but on my system at least, it only shows `OHCI` USBv1.1. I doubt you will get it to work with that release.